# Difference in usage of call read in karate

Tags: karate

I would like to know what is the difference between calling

```
 * call read("abcd.feature")
```

and

```
 * def variable =  call read("abcd.feature")
```

in a feature file.

I am observing a behavior that if a value assigned to a variable, the variable get reset after the first call, however the variable persist the value in the second case.

For example:

In 1st case

```
* def xyz = 1234
* call read("abcd.feature")
* print xyz is printing 0
```

However in 2nd case

```
* def xyz = 1234
* def variable = call read("abcd.feature")
* print xyz is printing 1234
```

I could not follow this behavior. If anyone could provide me the details it would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: please read the documentation: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#call-vs-read